# How do I update the array inside a class with an extension?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an extension which is reading a json file, but that's not the problem. The problem is updating the array in the class with the collection view methods. When I print the array length inside the extension I get 3, but when I print it inside the class where the collection view delegate methods are it prints 0.

```
extension JSON{

func findmultiple(viewclass: ViewController, @noescape predicate: JSON -> Bool) -> JSON? {

    if predicate(self) {
        return self
    }
    else {
        if let subJSON = (dictionary?.map { $0.1 } ?? array) {
            for json in subJSON {

                if let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(viewclass, predicate: predicate) {
                    let shorten = foundJSON["html"].stringValue
                    let firstshort = shorten.componentsSeparatedByString("   ")
                    let secondshort = firstshort[1].componentsSeparatedByString("\r")
                    let classname = secondshort[0]
                    if(classname == "STUDY HALL (INSTRUCT)"){
                        print("skip")
                    }else{
                        viewclass.importClass.append(classname)
                        print("fsgsfg \(viewclass.importgrades.count)") //prints("STUDY HALL", "CHEMISTRY", "PHYSICS")

                    }


                }

            }

        }

    }

    return nil
    }
 }
```

When I go to the class with the methods

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,  UICollectionViewDataSource{
   var importClass = [String]()

   func parseJSON(json: JSON){

    let predicate = {
        (json: JSON) -> Bool in
        if let jsonID = json["class"].string where jsonID == "sg-header-heading"{

            return true

        }
        return false
    }
    var backclass = ViewController()
    let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(backclass, predicate: predicate)

  }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: colcell = (collection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? colcell)!
    print(importClass) //prints []
    cell.classtitle.text = importClass[indexPath.item] //crashes `index out of range`
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the count for the CollectionView?

Comment: Yes I am setting the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ViewController class your variable is defined as ***importClasses*** and everywhere else its ***importClass***, is this just a typo as you should get a build error if its not.

Depending on how you are requesting the JSON you probably want to try calling `collectionView.reloadData()` once you have successfully retrieved the JSON.

*Edited*
The `findMultiple()` function is being passed a new instance of the view controller. It should be passed the current one.
`let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(self, predicate: predicate)` then you wouldn't need the line `var backclass = ViewController()`

Comment: Sorry typo on the question its the same in my code. When I try and reload collection view after the print("fsgsfg...") line it crashes

Comment: Can you post more of your code, specifically where you call `findmultiple()` and also your collectionview delegate methods.

Comment: I added the code to my question. The collection view for returning the count is equal to classgrades which is equal to the number of classes in this case three. So the count is three.

Comment: From the looks of it, you are assigning a new instance of your view controller to backclass. Try assigning **self**. You basically want to assign the viewController that you are executing the code from.

Comment: Where would I add the self?

Comment: `let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(self, predicate: predicate)` then you wouldn't need the line `var backclass = ViewController()`